# EJB Injection between EAR's on JBoss7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cdi

Is it possible to inject a StatelessBean from an other ear in the same application server without doing a JNDI lookup? As application server we are using JBoss 7.2.

I have the following setup:

```
EAR1
│   services1-0.1.jar
│   web-0.1.war
│
├───lib
│       EAR2-SERVICES-api-0.1.jar
│
└───META-INF
        application.xml
        beans.xml


EAR2
│   EAR2-SERVICES-impl-0.1.jar
│
├───lib
│       EAR2-SERVICES-api-0.1.jar
│
└───META-INF
        application.xml
        beans.xml
```

EAR2 contains for example the following service:

```
@Named
@Stateless
public class ServiceBean implements Service { }
```

and the interface:

```
@Remote
interface Service { }
```

The caller from EAR1 should only consider the API and not the implementation. How do I achieve, that this is guranteed. When I have to use the JNDI name, I have to know where the implementation is located.

For the injection of *Service* into EAR1 I tried *@Inject* and *@EJB*. But I always got `Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [Service] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject package.ServiceBean.service]`

The MANIFEST.MF has a dependency to deployment.EAR2.ear

Comment: The classloader isolates both ears so they don't see each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the application server's classloader isolates both applications, EAR1 cannot see the implementation of your service interface that's why it complains about unsatisfied dependencies. I recommend you to implement a producer method in EAR1 that looks up and ejb proxy that will call the remote ejb in EAR2. This [page](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project) describes how to look up a remote ejb. The producer method should look something like this:

```
 @Produces
 public Service produceService() {
   Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
   jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
   jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://localhost:4447");
   // create a context passing these properties
   Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
   // lookup
   Service service = (Service) ctx.lookup("<jndi name of the ejb>");
   return service;
}
```

This will satisfy the dependency CDI is complaining about.

Comment: Instead of a Producer I can use @EJB(lookup = <jndi name>) which is working fine, but I always have to know where the implementation is located. That's what I'm sad about. What would be a nice pattern that the user of Service only needs to know the API and nothing to know about the implementation.

Comment: You can't use @EJB(lookup=...) as you have to provide the address of the remote server where the implementation is deployed. The user of the Service has to know where the actual service is because it may me anywhere not only on the same server. You can use some kind of external configuration, even environment property to provide the address of the remote implementation.